# Launch application from bash terminal then kill terminal while leaving application running

Tags: linux, command-line, alias

I would like to use the following scenario for my favorite applications under Linux (Ubuntu 10.10) in order to save grabbing the mouse and clicking them:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>)
2. Type my alias for the application
   (eg: ff for firefox)
3. Have the application start and the
   terminal killed immediately, not
   when I close the application.
4. Define the dimensions and position
   of the application using the
   `--geometry` parameter from `gnome-terminal`

For now, I have created the following alias, but it does not behave as described:

```
alias ff="gnome-terminal --geometry 100x100-0+0 -e 'firefox'; exit"
```

Instead, it opens a new terminal, kills the first one, and kills the second one upon exiting firefox.

If I try the following instead:

```
alias ff2="firefox &; exit"
```

I get the error message:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

In fact, all these attempts fail:

```
alias ff="gnome-terminal --geometry 100x100-0+0 -e 'firefox'; exit"
alias ff2="firefox &; exit"
alias ff3="nohup firefox & ; exit"
alias ff4="nohup firefox; exit
```

How can I obtain the desired behavior?

Comment: Are you aware of the `&` operator and the `nohup` command?  Have you looked at them yet?

Comment: Hi S.Lott. Yes, I know about it. But I did not succeed in obtaining the desired behavior (specifically, killing the terminal) using the '&' operator either. Could it be done that way?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is it:

```
nohup firefox & 2> /dev/null; exit;
```

If you want to use an alias, simply do:

```
alias ff='nohup firefox & 2> /dev/null; exit;'
```

and watch the magic happen when you execute **ff**

Comment: The combination with the redirection of the output/error channels is key here. +1

Comment: Yes, I would never have thought to use the redirection in that case... Thanks karl!

Answer (score 1):

It's a SuperUser answer, but are you aware of the Alt-F2 shortcut?

Comment: Are you sure an alias can't execute multiple commands? Try my answer.

Comment: Whoops, I should have been quicker to fact-check.

Answer (score 0):

nohup command arguments & ; exit

Perhaps you might find it more productive to define keyboard shortcuts in your window manager to simply open the various programs of interest?

Comment: alias ff3="nohup firefox & ; exit" gives me the same error as for my ff2 attempt. Removing the & does not work either... sorry.

Comment: My answer is not a usage of the alias command, which is what introduces that problem.